# User input and output doesn't work in my assembly code

Tags: macos, assembly, x86, nasm, system-calls

The following program compiles without errors, but when run it doesn't prompt for any input and nothing prints. What's the problem, and how can I fix it?

I use these commands to assemble and link:

```
/usr/local/bin/nasm -f macho32 $1
ld -macosx_version_min 10.9.0 -lSystem -o run $filename.o -e _start -lc
```

My code is:

```
section .data
    ;New line string
    NEWLINE: db 0xa, 0xd
    LENGTH: equ $-NEWLINE

section .bss    
INPT: resd 1

section .text   
global _start
_start:


;Read character
mov eax, 0x3
mov ebx, 0x1
mov ecx, INPT
mov edx, 0x1
int 80h

;print character
mov eax, 0x4
mov ebx, 0x1
mov ecx, INPT
mov edx, 0x1
int 80h

;Print new line after the output 
mov eax, 0x4
mov ebx, 0x1
mov ecx, NEWLINE
mov edx, LENGTH
int 0x80

;Terminate
mov eax, 0x1
xor ebx, ebx
int 0x80
```

Comment: `int 0x80` works differently on OSX. Parameters to `int 0x80` (besides _EAX_) are passed on the stack in 32-bit code not in registers. The code you wrote looks like it was written for Linux. I'd recommend an [OS/X tutorial](https://filippo.io/making-system-calls-from-assembly-in-mac-os-x/) . As well the syscall numbers are different between Linux and OSX.

Comment: As well once you convert your code to OS/X, you should be aware that Standard Input is file descriptor 0, and Standard Output is file descriptor 1. You use Standard Output (1) for both input and output which is asking for problems.

Comment: @Michael Petch Yes, you are right, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are signs in your code that you may have been using a Linux tutorial when producing code for OS/X(BSD). Linux and OS/X have differing *SYSCALL* calling conventions. In OS/X 32-bit programs `int 0x80` requires parameters (except the syscall in *EAX*) to be passed on a stack.

The important things to be aware of with 32-bit *SYSCALL*s via `int 0x80` on OS/X are:

> - arguments passed on the stack, pushed right-to-left
> - you must allocate an additional 4 bytes (a *DWORD*) on the stack after you push all the arguments
> - syscall number in the eax register
> - call by interrupt 0x80

After pushing arguments on the stack in reverse order for `int 0x80` you must allocate an additional 4 bytes (a *DWORD*) on the stack. The value in that memory location on the stack doesn't matter. This requirement is an artifact from an [old UNIX convention](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/developers-handbook/x86-system-calls.html).

A list of the *SYSCALL* numbers and their parameters can be found in the *APPLE* [header files](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1504.3.12/bsd/kern/syscalls.master). You'll need these *SYSCALL*s:

> ```
> 1 AUE_EXIT    ALL { void exit(int rval); }
> 3 AUE_NULL    ALL { user_ssize_t read(int fd, user_addr_t cbuf, user_size_t nbyte); } 
> 4 AUE_NULL    ALL { user_ssize_t write(int fd, user_addr_t cbuf, user_size_t nbyte); }
> ```

I have commented some example code that would be similar in functionality to what you may have been attempting to achieve:

```
section .data
    ;New line string
    NEWLINE: db 0xa, 0xd
    LENGTH: equ $-NEWLINE

section .bss
    INPT: resd 1

global _start

section .text
_start:
    and     esp, -16      ; Make sure stack is 16 byte aligned at program start
                          ;     not necessary in this example since we don't call 
                          ;     external functions that conform to the OS/X 32-bit ABI

    push    dword 1       ; Read 1 character
    push    dword INPT    ; Input buffer
    push    dword 0       ; Standard input = FD 0
    mov     eax, 3        ; syscall sys_read
    sub     esp, 4        ; Extra 4 bytes on stack needed by int 0x80
    int     0x80
    add     esp, 16       ; Restore stack

    push    dword 1       ; Print 1 character
    push    dword INPT    ; Output buffer = buffer we read characters into
    push    dword 1       ; Standard output = FD 1
    mov     eax, 4        ; syscall sys_write
    sub     esp, 4        ; Extra 4 bytes on stack needed by int 0x80
    int     0x80
    add     esp, 16       ; Restore stack

    push    dword LENGTH  ; Number of characters to write
    push    dword NEWLINE ; Write the data in the NEWLINE string
    push    dword 1       ; Standard output = FD 1
    mov     eax, 4        ; syscall sys_write
    sub     esp, 4        ; Extra 4 bytes on stack needed by int 0x80
    int     0x80
    add     esp, 16       ; Restore stack

    push    dword 0       ; Return value from program = 0
    mov     eax, 1        ; syscall sys_exit
    sub     esp, 4        ; Extra 4 bytes on stack needed by int 0x80
    int     0x80
```

The `and esp, -16` is only necessary if you need to align the stack to a 16-byte boundary as a baseline for future stack operations. If you intend to call external functions that conform to the [OS/X 32-bit ABI](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/LowLevelABI/130-IA-32_Function_Calling_Conventions/IA32.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002492-SW4) the stack is expected to be 16-byte aligned immediately preceding a function *CALL*. This alignment is not necessary for system calls via `int 0x80`.

You should be able to assemble and link it with:

```
nasm -f macho32 test.asm -o test.o
ld -macosx_version_min 10.9.0 -o test test.o -e _start -lSystem
```

And run it with:

```
./test
```