# Program will assemble and link but not run(ASM) on OSX

Tags: macos, assembly, x86, nasm

So I am in a basic assembly class and the issue im having is I have gotten the first assignment to create the .o file and link. However I get no output when I try to run the code.  I have been searching for a answer to this but have seen no response

Here is the actual program

```
SECTION .data ; Section containing initialized data
EatMsg: db "Eat at Joe's!",10
EatLen: equ $-EatMsg
SECTION .bss ; Section containing uninitialized data
SECTION .text ; Section containing code
global start ; Linker needs this to find the entry point!
start:
nop ; This no-op keeps gdb happy...
mov eax,4 ; Specify sys_write call
mov ebx,1 ; Specify File Descriptor 1: Standard Output
mov ecx,EatMsg ; Pass offset of the message
mov edx,EatLen ; Pass the length of the message
int 80H ; Make kernel call
mov eax,1 ; Code for Exit Syscall
mov ebx,0 ; Return a code of zero
int 80H ; Make kernel call
```

Then I compile using
`nasm -f macho -o eatsyscall.o  eatsyscall.asm`

And finally link using

`ld eatsyscall.o -o  eatsyscall`

However when I use the terminal command `./eatsyscall`

I get no output at all.  I'm not really sure where I'm going wrong here and would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Did you happen to use a Linux tutorial? With 32-bit OS/X programs system calls are done via `int 0x80` and have arguments pushed on the stack rather than registers (as well OS/X does use different system call numbers than Linux)

Comment: yes I was following a tutorial provided by the professor, I had to change the nasm cmd from `elf` to `macho`.  But do i need to make it `macho32` or someting along those lines?

Comment: This is Linux code it will not run as expected directly on OS/X. You either have to convert this code to 32-bit OS/X (passing int 0x80 parameters via stack rather than registers and use appropriate OS/X system call numbers if needed). The alternative is to use Virtual Machine software like VirtualBox, install Linux inside of it and build and run your software from there. If you want to use 32-bit OS/X system calls you may wish to see this SO answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36106091/3857942