# Assembly code isn't executing from terminal after I compiled. It shows up in the same folder?

Tags: macos, assembly, x86, nasm, system-calls

Here's what I wrote in the terminal

```
Ayeshas-MacBook-Pro:CMPE 102 Ayesha$ nasm -f macho32 -O0 eatsyscall.asm
Ayeshas-MacBook-Pro:CMPE 102 Ayesha$ ld eatsyscall.o -o eatsyscall
Ayeshas-MacBook-Pro:CMPE 102 Ayesha$ ./eatsyscall 
Ayeshas-MacBook-Pro:CMPE 102 Ayesha$ ./eatsyscall 
Ayeshas-MacBook-Pro:CMPE 102 Ayesha$
```

And this is the code:

```
SECTION .data           ; Section containing initialised data
    EatMsg: db "Eat at Joe's!",10
    EatLen: equ $-EatMsg

SECTION .bss            ; Section containing uninitialized data

SECTION .text           ; Section containing code
global  start           ; Linker needs this to find the entry point!

start:
    nop         ; This no-op keeps gdb happy...
    mov eax,4       ; Specify sys_write call
    mov ebx,1       ; Specify File Descriptor 1: Standard Output
    mov ecx,EatMsg      ; Pass offset of the message
    mov edx,EatLen      ; Pass the length of the message
    int 80H         ; Make kernel call

    MOV eax,1       ; Code for Exit Syscall
    mov ebx,0       ; Return a code of zero
    int 80H         ; Make kernel call
```

I got the `.o` file, however it doesn't show the output. Also in the folder, it has the output file just 'eatsyscall' and has a picture of the terminal, but it's not running for some reason!

Comment: You are attempting to use linux system calls on mac. That won't work. Go search for a mac sample program.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I tried it and it gave me a similar error. Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_start", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for inferred architecture i386

Comment: What version of OS/X are you using?

Comment: @MichaelPetch 10.13.3

Comment: If you used my other post and got that error I assume you assembled your own code. The problem is that your code here should use `_start` instead of `start`. So in your code So `global start` should be `global _start` and `start:` should be `_start:` . Then you can use the method to assemble and link in my other post

Comment: I see it in my folder as a just "test0" but the output is not displaying on the terminal

Comment: Did you look at the code in the answer I linked to and did you try it?

Comment: The code you wrote here is for Linux, it will not work in OS/X. Did you look at or try the code in the SO answer I have marked as a duplicate. The code you should look at is in this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/36106091/3857942

Comment: Ohh okay, i missed the --> arguments passed on the stack, pushed right-to-left
you must allocate an additional 4 bytes (a DWORD) on the stack after you push all the arguments
syscall number in the eax register
call by interrupt 0x80

Comment: If the other answer helped you out, you can consider upvoting the other answer. If you find you the other question is related to your you should mark this one as a duplicate I have linked to.